# Xamarin Forms - TapGestureRecognizer not working for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am creating list of image in a loop and attaching 
 a TapGestureRecognizer to each of them to run a method. It is working on Android but not on iOS.  Why is that?  Is there a problem with it being in a Grid or in a ScrollView?

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var i in files)
        {
            Image image = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
            image.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new System.Uri(i));
            Button button = new Button();
            link = i;

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                ViewImage(i);

            };

            image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            gridy.Children.Add(image, 0, num);
            num++;
        }
```

Here is my Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="YHTS.Gallery"
         Title="Gallery"
         BackgroundColor="Black">

<ScrollView >
    <Grid x:Name="gridy">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: When I tap on the image, the method ViewImage(I) isn't run.

Comment: Try to add TapGestureRecognizer after iteration because event is running with loop.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked like a charm in the iOS simulator. Perhaps its related to the implementation of ViewImage? If you put a breakpoint on that line does the app break on it?

Comment: @StevenThewissen  You are right, i added in a displayalert in the method and it fired as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `InputTransparent="True"` of the `View`

Comment: @Kowalski  could you please explain on why this works. I mean why do we need to set the scrollview to InputTransparent in iOS